# TP-Link AC600 Archer T2U Nano driver for Kubuntu 19.10 not able to catch 5Ghz wifi

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb, kubuntu, 19.10

My Kubuntu version is 19.10 The laptop is LENOVO G580.
TP-Link AC600 Archer T2U Nano driver able to catch 2.4Ghz wifi but not able to catch 5Ghz wifi

I followed the steps here but with no luck.

Here is the first solution:

```
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8812au-1.git
cd rtl8812au-1
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

and it gives these errors:

```
About to run dkms install steps...
Error! DKMS tree already contains: rtl8812au-5.3.4
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' -j8 KVER=5.3.0-26-generic KSRC=/lib/modules/5.3.0-26-            
generic/build......(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8812au: 5.3.4 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.3.0-26-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/make.log for more information.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' -j8 KVER=5.3.0-26-generic KSRC=/lib/modules/5.3.0-26-        
generic/build......(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8812au: 5.3.4 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.3.0-26-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/make.log for more information.
Finished running dkms install steps.
```

Then I went to the second solution:

```
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

which yielded no errors, but still not able to catch 5Ghz wifi

here is the output of sudo dkms status:

```
bcmwl, 6.30.223.271+bdcom, 5.3.0-7625-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 440.44, 5.3.0-7625-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au, 5.3.4: added
rtl8812au, 5.6.4.2, 5.3.0-7625-generic, x86_64: installed
system76, 1.0.6~1568425791~19.10~5ba8ce9, 5.3.0-7625-generic, x86_64: installed
system76_acpi, 1.0.1~1571170639~19.10~d625910, 5.3.0-7625-generic, x86_64: installed
system76-io, 1.0.1~1559663713~19.10~ea5f61a, 5.3.0-7625-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Please advice, I have been struggling with this for so long!